# Using of Sitecore's XPath builder to test queries

Tags: xpath, sitecore

i'm getting started with sitecore and i just discovered this tool sitecore offers to test our queries:

[image: Xpath builder test]

My problem is i just can't make it return results and i do know this query works perfectly cause i've been using it on my project right now.
There is probably a problem of syntax somwhere i don't know.
Thank you for helping me to put some light on this !

Comment: Can you tell me what tool this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to tell due to how bits of that are redacted (there might be other syntax errors hiding under the boxes), but there's one obvious issue there, I think: You don't need the `"query:"` bit on the beginning of what you've typed.

In general, if the API or web form your filling in can only take a query expression you can leave the `"query:"` bit off. But if you're putting text into somewhere that might take a query or might take something else then `"query:"` is needed to tell Sitecore what it's looking at.

Comment: No problem - glad to help.